# get colors on list products magento

Tags: php, magento

I need a small amount of help to start developing a script to get the color labels on list products in Magento. I do not want to switch the pictures on click, I simply want to show that there is more than 1 color available on that particular product.

Ok, i get the final script, but i cannot get the result of pictures below

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(155); ?>" width="155" height="155" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
</a>
```

Script to get the associated images on list.

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();?> 
<?php if($_images){?> 
<?php     $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?> 
<a href="#"> 
    <img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(200, 130); ?>” width="200" height="130" alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /> 
</a>
<?php     }?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: My mistake, this code is working perfect. i put in list not in grid.

Comment: Answer and accept your answer to this question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script from the question is working perfect, just not the right place to explode it.